# How do you use a batch to modify certain columns in a CSV file?

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a simple CSV file with six values per row (%a-%f)
The %a is text string the other values are all integers.
My problem is that for values %d and %e cannot be odd and must be rounded up.
Should I search for each odd integer one at a time or is there a simpler way?

My CSV file looks like this:

ww-xx-yy-zzz,1,2,3,4,5

Comment: must each column be filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script accomplishes what you are trying to do:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "CSVFILE=data.csv"     & rem (input file)
set "NEWFILE=data_new.csv" & rem (output file)
set "ROUNDEVEN=#" & rem (empty to round to odd, non-empty to round to even)
set "ROUNDUP=#"   & rem (empty to round down, non-empty to round up)

if defined ROUNDEVEN (set /A ROUNDEVEN=0) else (set /A ROUNDEVEN=-1)
if defined ROUNDUP (set /A ROUNDUP=1) else (set /A ROUNDUP=0)

> "%NEWFILE%" (
    for /F "usebackq eol=, tokens=1-6 delims=," %%A in ("%CSVFILE%") do (
        set "TEXT=%%A"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "ROUNDED="
        for %%Z in (%%D %%E) do (
            set /A VALUE=^(%%Z+ROUNDUP-ROUNDEVEN^)/2*2+ROUNDEVEN
            set "ROUNDED=!ROUNDED!,!VALUE!"
        )
        echo(!TEXT!,%%B,%%C!ROUNDED!,%%F
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

Here is the input CSV data of your question (file `data.csv`):

> ```
> ww-xx-yy-zzz,1,2,3,4,5
> ```

...and the corresponding output CSV data (file `data_new.csv`):

> ```
> ww-xx-yy-zzz,1,2,4,4,5
> ```

The script only works if the following conditions are fulfilled:

- the input CSV file contains exactly 6 columns; too many are simply ignored, too few may disrupt column/field mapping;
- none of the columns/fields of the input CSV data is empty;
- only the first column of the input CSV data contains text data, all the others contain integers;
- none of the integer values to round has got leading zeros;

Comment: It works great thankyou so much... Where would I find options like roundup and roundeven? I have been having trouble editing my CSV files. This saves me a huge pain in the neck, again thankyou

Comment: I do not understand what you mean (roundup/roundeven)... Anyway, what editing trouble do you have problems with?

Comment: The editing trouble I have is that eventually I want to rename all files in one folder to each 'name' in the %a column. Should I edit my CSV file or is there another solution?

Comment: So you have multiple CSV files and you want to rename each one to the text in tge first column? of which row -- the first one? Anyway, this is a completely different topic, so I suggest that you post another question, including some sample data/files, your efforts and what exactly you have trouble with...

Comment: My thoughts exactly, you have already helped me from so much tedious editing, thankyou problem definitely solved!

Comment: You are welcome! Since my answer solved your problem, please consider to accept it; this is the way to say "thank you" on SO and helps also other users having the same problem... thanks!

Comment: @JoeTreviño - click the check mark to the left of the answer.