# Change character in batch file

Tags: csv, batch-file

Currently i have a csv export with the following output

```
number;sentence;text;text;text;text;text;text;18.05.2012;time;text;text;number
number;sentence;text;text;text;text;text;text;18.05.2012;time;text;text;number
number;sentence;text;text;text;text;text;text;#;time;text;text;number
number;sentence;text;text;text;text;text;text;#;time;text;text;number
```

Notice that it sometimes happens that a date is not present, instead "#" has been inserted. The # is also present in other parts of the CSV file, however this shouldn't be impacted. Which currently happens

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "skip=4 tokens=1-9* delims=," %%f in (input.csv) do if not "%%f"=="" (
    set "line=%%f"
    set "line=!line:#"=!"
    echo(!line!
)) > output.csv

endlocal
```

Any pointers where i go wrong?

Comment: This is not how this site works! Stack Overflow is not a free code/script writing service, it is a Q&A resource for programmers. Please read the [tour] and learn [ask] here! Basically you have to try to implement your task by yourself; when stuck, come back here, ask a specific question and provide a [mcve] of your coding attempt.

Comment: Must it be using only Batch?

Comment: Preferably in batch only yes. If it's possible at least

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you use a batch to modify certain columns in a CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193222/how-do-you-use-a-batch-to-modify-certain-columns-in-a-csv-file)

Comment: Another thing you should do **before** asking is research. The link to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36199300/6811411) from @aschipfl I provided shows concepts you've to adapt to your needs.

Comment: to bring you onto the right track: think about `"tokens=1-9,* delims=,"`

Comment: to literally answer the meanwhile deleted question "However this replaces the # in the complete file. Can this be done for the standalone ones?": `set "line=!line:;#;=!"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you didn't quite understand the "tokens" thing. The first token is set to the given variable (`%%a`), the next tokens are assigned to the (alphabetically) following variables (`%%b`, `%%c`, ...). You need to change the ninth token (`%%i`), so you have to retrieve tokens 1 to 9 and `*` for "the rest". Also your delimiter was wrong (your text file has `;`, so you need `delims=;`)

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

(for /f "skip=4 tokens=1-9* delims=;" %%a in (input.csv) do (
    if "%%i"=="#" (set "data=") else (set "data=%%i")
    echo(%%a;%%b;%%c;%%d;%%e;%%f;%%g;%%h;!data!;%%j
)) > output.csv
endlocal
```

(Of course you also could start with `%%f`, but then your ninth token is `%%n` - it's easier to read when you start with `a`)

Keep in mind, consecutive delimiters are treated as one. So if you have empty fields (`...;text;;text;...`) your tokenization goes wild.

Comment: I tried to run the above code but it is not providing any output file

Comment: How many lines does `input.csv` have? (`skip=4` skips the first 4 lines and your example has exactly 4 lines)

Comment: It has over 1000 lines. I inserted this command to get rid of all the unneeded information that is initially created when generating the file.

Comment: I forgot a closing `)`. Edited. Please try again.

Comment: In regards to a comment that was mentioned "Keep in mind, consecutive delimiters are treated as one. So if you have empty fields (...;text;;text;...) your tokenization goes wild. " If this needs to be applied also to the 10th column will this cause any issues?

Comment: no, the `*` actually means "do no further tokenization (and take the rest of the line as a single token)".

Comment: Great, one last question: can the else command be used to change the date format to YYYY-MM-DD instead to just copying? I found some answers where people would advise power shell for this. Would that be the preferred way forward in this case?

Comment: yes. You will need the [set](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) command to extract substrings and put them together in the desired order.